# Problem with calculating site specific and year geomean in R with pipes

Tags: r

I'm making some corrections to someone else's old water quality code and trying to make it more efficient. I'm trying to replace a loop with code that will take the geomean by water body by year that contains more than 3 samples. Overall, this is working, but I noticed one value that's incorrect and I can't determine why. 
The initial data looks like this

```
Name         ID    Date       ChlA
Hazel Hill  7387  2017-07-07  52.297
Hazel Hill  7387  2017-08-02  57.23100
Hazel Hill  7387  2017-06-02  55.57200
Hazel Hill  7387  2017-06-15  42.64800 
Hazel Hill  7387  2018-06-01  63.8000
Hazel Hill  7387  2018-07-06  43.2000
Hazel Hill  7387  2018-08-01  66.9000
Hazel Hill  7387  2018-08-23  49.4000
```

Here's what I'm doing right now

```
# Creating own geomean function that requires at least 4 values
gm_mean = function(x,na.rm=T){
  ifelse(length(na.omit(x))>3,
  exp(sum(log(x[x>0]),na.rm=na.rm)/length(x)),
  NA)
}

Geo_data<-alldata %>% group_by(ID[![enter image description here][1]][1],year(Date)) %>% 
summarise(gm_mean(ChlA))
```

I know there's packages that contain a geomean function, but so far it's been faster to use this since it considers that there must be more than 3 values of data per year (I'm open to other suggestions though). I'm also taking the geomean of other data in this line as well and included a picture of the data itself. 
This has been working for almost all the data *except* this specific year and waterbody. It should be 54.9, but instead the output is 24.7. Am I missing something? Any ideas on what's going wrong or suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: I guess `year(Date)` should be `year(Year)`, based on your sample data? On a side note, do you really need `year(...)` here at all?

Comment: PS. I can't confirm: `alldata %>% group_by(Name, Year) %>% summarise(gm_mean(ChlA))` returns 54.9.

Comment: Whoops. The actual data has a date that's yyyy-mm-dd. I was trying to simplify it for the example

Comment: Can you change the sample data to be more representative? Because with the current sample data the issue is not reproducible; i.e. `gm_mean` returns the correct value of 54.9.

Comment: Ok. I added a year and some more complexity as well as picture of the actual data. Those are the actual values though. I really don't know why this is happening...

Comment: Actually, I just found an NA value that was hiding at the top of this group of data for this year. That's what's causing all of this.

Answer (score 0):

There was an NA value in the dataset that wasn't originally showing up due to a difference in another variable. Switching to geometric.mean in the function gm_mean instead of exp(sum(log(x[x>0]) helped to avoid this issue and avoid problems caused by NA values.